# Is it possible to send push notifications without APNS (using signalR)?

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications, signalr

Is it possible to send push notifications without APNS (using signalR)?

ps: the push notifications backend is using signalR, which they(developer of the backend and android app) said, it can be done without go thru Google(GCM) for android

Answer (score 2):

As per this [site](http://signalr.net/)

> SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and
>   gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it
>   isn't, while your application code stays the same.

It can used for real time communications like chatting as its relying on sockets.

> Is it possible to send push notifications without APNS (using
>   signalR)?

You can trigger Local Notifications in iOS and Notifications in Android through your app if you have coded your app to the trigger them based on your conditions and data that you received from your server

WebSockets are active till your app is active. If the user or OS has killed your app, the connection will break and SignalR won't be able to communicate with your App until your app is active again and establish a connection to your server.

Push Notifications are like Instant Messages that are meant to be delivered without worrying the status of your app i.e. App is running or not.

APNS & FCM/GCM are designed carefully and efficiently to deliver your message(Push Notification) instantly and securely with less mobile's CPU, battery and Network usage.